# PHP ActiveRecord Datetime Format

Tags: php, phpactiverecord

I had a small problem when using PHP ActiveRecord, every project i always change 3 file :

*Column.php*, *Model.php*, *Connection.php* and replace **Y-m-d H:i:s T** to **Y-m-d H:i:s**

How to change it easy ?? Make new class maybe ??

My setup :

```
$database = array(
    'connection' => 'local',
    'local' => 'mysql://username:password@localhost/database?charset=utf8',
    'server' => 'mysql://username:password@localhost/database?charset=utf8'
);

ActiveRecord\Config::initialize(function($config) use ($database) {
    $config->set_connections($database);
    $config->set_default_connection($database['connection']);
});
```

Comment: You have the same string `Y-m-d H:i:s` as replace from and replace to

Comment: no, as default is **Y-m-d H:i:s T** and i replace to **Y-m-d H:i:s** (remove **T**)

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't see "T", sorry. Why are you replacing it, does it cause any problems? We're using phpactiverecord for years and it works just fine without this replacement (we're using MySQL).

Comment: when i insert new record without replace **T** : `DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2015-01-09 13:25:29 WIB) at position 20 (W): The timezone could not be found in the database`. Didn't you get it, i use MySQL too ?

Comment: If that's an option for you, change PHP timezone to UTC, that should help.

Comment: I use date_default_timezone_set(Asia/Jakarta), i think `function assign_attribute` at `Model.php` always use `if ($value instanceof \DateTime)` not `if ($value instanceof DateTime)`

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following line after your initialize call.

```
ActiveRecord\Connection::$datetime_format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
```